# External library not loading

Tags: javascript, twig

I am currently developing a website and I am using `Twig` to add/load all the libraries I need on my page.
Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with two of those libraries. 
Let's say I have a library X and a library Y. If I load my libraries like this :

```
{% block body %}
//getting lots of different libs
{{ getJS('libs') }}
//getting the internal lib X 
{{ getJS('libX') }}
//getting external lib Y
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/mylibY.js">
{% endblock %}
```

The `getJS()` function only parse  with different paths.

In this case, the lib Y isn't loaded in my body. If I put the `<script>` tag before getting the libX, the lib X isn't loaded...
If I put the lib Y before the global at the beginning of the block, only the lib Y will be loaded.
If I put only one of the libs, it works fine.

Since the twig only parse my  tags in the `HTML`, how can I force the `HTML` to load my lib X and only then load my lib Y?

Thanks for your answers.
If you have any questions don't hesitate since the subject is a bit hard to understand/explain.

Comment: That's not possible in pure HTML. You'll need a module loader like AMD or CommonJS for that, which are able to resolve dependencies.

Comment: You mean `lib y` is depedent on `lib x`? They don't run separately?

Comment: No they are independant and they should run separately. In fact, they do completely different things.

Comment: With some more research, I found out that the script of `lib y` does this : `document.querySelector("script[src*='myLibY.js']").src` and cannot read the property src. How can the script be at the same time executed and unable to find the script in the document ?